# Trying to install steam on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: steam

I have tried to install steam from the software centre, steam website and through apt-get and I always get this error:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for james:
...........................................................................
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.48) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libelf1:i386 (>= 0.142) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libllvm3.4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                    libtxc-dxtn0:i386
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxfixes3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libudev0:i386 but it is not installable
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

I have tried doing:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

and it still does not work.

Any help at all?

Comment: Run this command : `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

then just run *Steam* through the *Terminal* (at least the first time). That's always worked for me when I had issues with dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Four of your packages have no upgrade path or are broken and hence you are getting the said error. You can verify which packages are broken from *apt-get* log file by running the command:

```
gedit /var/log/apt/term.log
```

You can remove them as follows:

```
sudo apt-get remove [package_name]
```

If that doesn't work you may opt for *aptitude*.

**Aptitude is used for common package management functions, such as installation, removal, and upgrade.**

You can install it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude -fy remove [package_name]
```

After removing the package try to install the Steam again.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install steam -y
```